# Draw route on map on runtime by getting current location with GPS? iPhone (iOS6)

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, sdk

I want to get my current location with GPS and when I move the path travelled is  drawn on map. How can i do that?

Comment: for iPhone development ios6

Comment: Also look at Apple's Breadcrumb sample app http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/Breadcrumb/Introduction/Intro.html

Comment: have any another example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can draw route travelled using MKPolyline